# Why file.write() is appending in r+ mode in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assume I have a file `content.txt`, with the content `Ex nihilo nihil fit`. I am willing to replace it with `Ex nihilo nihil est`. The code is:

```
with open("content.txt", "r+") as f:
    content = f.read()
    content = content.replace("fit", "est")
    print(content)
    f.write(content)
    f.close()
```

After that, the content of the file becomes:

```
Ex nihilo nihil fit
Ex nihilo nihil est
```

Why? The only thing I need is `Ex nihilo nihil est`. What is the correct code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`r+` opens the file and puts a pointer at the first byte. When you use `f.read()` the pointer moves to the end of the file, so when you try to write it starts at the end of the file. To move back to the start (so you can override), use `f.seek(0)`:

```py
with open("text.txt", "r+") as f:
    content = f.read()
    content = content.replace("fit", "est")
    print(content)
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate(0)
    f.write(content)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Your answer is incorrect since it does not resize the file to the new content. It only produces the correct result by accident since the old and new content is the same length.

Comment: @KurtisRader my answer is correct in terms of it answers the question. The only way that it is wrong is that I didn't truncate the file at the end in case the new size was smaller, but I've now edited it to include it.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you are appending the modified content to the file.

What you want is to clear the content first.
You can use seek and truncate for that.

```
with open("content.txt", "r+") as f:
    content = f.read()
    content = content.replace("fit", "est")
    print(content)
    f.seek(0)  # move to first byte
    f.truncate()  # delete content
    f.write(content)
```

Comment: To use truncate to clear a file, you should use truncate(0), without the 0 it will just resize to the contents I believe

Comment: The truncate() method resizes the file to the given number of bytes.
If the size is not specified, the current position will be used.

https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/file/truncate.html

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below if you want to replace a string in a `.txt` file :

```
with open("content.txt", 'r') as file :
    content = file.read()

content = content.replace('fit', 'est')

with open("content.txt", 'w') as file:
    file.write(content)
```