# Python: readline after write() appends to EOF, not to read position

Tags: python

It seems when I write directly to a file using

```
with open("testfile", "r+") as my_file:

    text = my_file.write("========")
```

It will overwrite the first few characters and replace it with the "write" string....Logical!

However, adding a mere my_file.readline() (or readlines()) **AFTER** the file-write statement would cause it to write to the end of the file even though the seek is at the beginning of the file. Here is the example

```
with open("testfile", "r+") as my_file:

    text = my_file.write("========")
    print(my_file.readline())
```

Any clue why file handle in Python behaves that way?

TIA,

Can use this as a testfile to save some typing

```
first line
second line
third line
fourth line
```

Comment: Edited the title to more closely describe the problem. Funny thing, we had a question caused by the same underlying mechanism already asked and answered within the last few days; I wonder why it's coming up now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55539987/unexpected-read-write-behaviour-in-r-mode-in-python-text-files is one related older question, but I'm certain we have another one with a better answer as well.

Comment: Another one, but not the one I remember from this week either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271216/why-is-there-an-issue-with-reading-and-writing-to-the-same-file?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yet another, not as comprehensive an answer as the instance I'm looking for, but good enough for the use case here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73766401/why-file-write-is-appending-in-r-mode-in-python?rq=3

Comment: When I try this it writes the text at the end of the file, as if the append option was selected. But it reads from the beginning of the file so the original text is unchanged.